# hiding files from wget

Tags: curl, wget

If I move my sqlite3 database one level above my domain directory structure, will that escape the coverage from wget --recursive ?

For example:

```
wget -e robots=off --wait 1 --recursive --html-extension --page-requisites --convert-links "www.mydomain.org"
```

Will the database file placed one level above the home directory invisible to the this recursive wget?

Comment: The same way you will hide it from listing over `http`.

Comment: explain a little bit please

Answer (score 0):

wget can download a file, if you can download the file from browser or through other means. wget cannot download a file, if you cannot download from browser. What you are asking is nothing to do with wget. It is where you place your DB file in your web server, so that, others won't be able to download the file.

If your database is not linked from any of your files, then even if it is within the domain directory structure, wget cannot download the file, because, it cannot get the link from anywhere.

Ideally, the database should not be in your domain directory structure, so that, even if somebody gets the link through some other means, they should not be able to download it.